# How can I use ansible playbook to get group name on each of hosts?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I using ansible playbook for audit script
I use ansible playbook with Jinja2 for creating a dashboard in HTML
Here is my inventory

```
[Ubuntu16]
target1.com
[CentOS7]
target2.com
```

I run all hosts to check the connection and I want to do the following steps

1. Count all hosts in inventory separate by group
2. In case of connection passed, register to a parameter (separate by group)
3. and then send a parameter of the result to Jinja2 template

The result should be like this

```
Ubuntu16_sum_all = 1
Ubuntu16_alive = 1
Ubuntu16_dead = 1
CentOS7_sum_all = 1
CentOS7_alive = 1
CentOS7_dead = 1
```

I have no idea to get a group name of a host while I running all hosts in the playbook. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so there is a direct way of using the inventory format above directly. My suggestion would be take the hostnames inside a variable something like below:

```
---
hosts:
  - Ubuntu:
      - 1
      - 2
  - Centos:
      - 1
      - 2
  - Fedora:
      - 1
      - 2
```

In the above inventory you can loop through all the hosts name directly

Comment: But, I want to create template in the one time. Because I need a centralized dashboard includes the result of centos and ubuntu on the same page.

Comment: Since your need is to create a template best thing as per me would be to refer the above file as vars file. Check if the connection exists if the connection exists then create a template file for all the valid connections